# How should data be structured for lineplots with vue/chart.js

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am retrieving data from an api (working) and generating a line plot with `vue-chartjs`.

However only the first two points are plotted. I must have my data structured in the wrong way but I don't know what it is expecting.
Here is my component:

```
import { Line } from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
  extends: Line,
  props: {
    chartdata: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartdata);
  }
};
```

And in my `App.vue` file, I have this simple template:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="Chart">
        <h2>LineChart</h2>
        <line-chart v-if="loaded" :chartdata="chartdata"></line-chart>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and this script:

```
<script>
import LineChart from './components/LineChart.js'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: { LineChart },
  data:() => ({
    loaded: false,
    chartdata: null
  }),
  async mounted () {
    this.loaded = false;
    try {
      let mydata = await fetch("http://myserver00/api/load/myserver02")
      .then(stream => stream.json())
      .then(mydata => {
        let usercpu = [];
        mydata.forEach(record => {
          usercpu.push( record.cpu.user );
        });
        this.usercpu = usercpu;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
    this.loaded = true;
    this.chartdata = {
      datasets: [
        {label: 'CPU', data: this.usercpu}
        ]
      };
  }
}
</script>
```

As you may notice, I'm trying to system data from `psutils` to monitor servers. The original record from the api has several fields. This example just shows my attempt at CPU usage.

The browser tools show the data I expect, but apparently not what the chart expects. Here's a view of the data from the chrome vue devtools extension

[image]

Edit: to make sure the data is actually loaded,  I added {{chartdata}} into my template and I see it all. Here is how it starts, the array goes on with all the data array. And the actual plot again shows only the first two data points.

```
{ "datasets": [ { "label": "CPU", "data": [ 2.7, 2.9, 3
```

Comment: do you need stream.json.parse?

Comment: I wouldn't guess that's it as the data looks okay in devtools. And I'm using the fetch api (more info here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) so I *think* I'm okay on that part. Do you think I should add stream.json.parse?

Comment: You're right, it looks like the fetch() method does the parsing under the hood, so that wouldn't be the right fix. 

This doc looks like it has the right model to follow: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-api-data

Comment: thanks, that article is what I started with but assigning the data directly (in their case, `userlist`) resulted in no plot at all. As it is, it plots only the first two values, 4.7 and 4.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it; I needed to re-read the doc for Chartjs. So here's the mounted function now. See that I had to put in x and y values for each point.

```
async mounted () {
  this.loaded = false;
  try {
    let usercpu = [];
    await fetch("http://server/api/load/server02")
    .then(stream => stream.json())
    .then(mydata => { mydata.forEach(record => { 
      usercpu.push( { y: record.cpu.user, x: record.date });});});
    this.loaded = true;
    this.chartdata = { 
      datasets: [ {
        fill: false, 
        pointRadius: 0, 
        borderWidth: 2,
        label: 'CPU', 
        data: usercpu 
        } ] };
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

Also, in the data portion of the default function I had to add axes. I'm not exactly sure why, but even when the data was okay (above) I still couldn't see the plot. So when I added the axes, there everything was:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                  unit: "hour",
                  displayFormats: {
                    hour: "M/DD @ hA"
                  },
                  tooltipFormat: "MMM. DD @ hA"
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: "Date/Time"
                },
            ticks: { autoSkip: true, maxTicksLimit: 5},
            position: 'bottom'
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,
                suggestedMax: 10
            }
        }]
    }
```

And of course I had to include the options in the directive:

```
    <template>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="container">
        <div id="cpu">
        <h2>Server02</h2>
        <line-chart v-if="loaded"  :chartdata="chartdata" :options="options"></line-chart>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
```